# Transfer Ether between wallets

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets, myetherwallet, exchanges

I am using Kraken to purchase Ether and now I want to use some third-party wallet to withdraw Ether and wallet should provide an API to transfer Ether from my wallet to another wallet.

MyEtherWallet does not provide any such API,is there any other wallet like MEW that exposes an API for transferring between wallets ?

Comment: Why not use directly the [Kraken API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api)?

Comment: I think Kraken only allows withdraw in 1 account. Right ? I want to transfer Ether to multiple account as need arises.

Comment: The API mentions giving the key of one registered address, I don't know how many can be registered, I guess if your destinations addresses are not fixed beforehand, then no, can't use Kraken API.

Comment: So, the destinations addresses(receivers) should belong to Kraken ? I think an account on crypto-currency exchange is mandatory for other users as they have to convert the Ether into real money. Correct ?